# Highmaps missing cities for California State

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

As I was looking for some of cities (San Jose, Berkeley, ParloAlto, Cupertino, Davis, Mountain View, Pasadena, Sunnyvale, Irvine, Livermore, Edwards, Whitmore, Loma Linda, Standford, Redwood City, El Segundo, Moss Landing,Marina Del Rey etc..) under california state could not be found highlighted in Highmaps as seen from the below link

http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo#countries/us/us-ca-all

Are there any possible solutions or any support for the mentioned problem above?

Comment: The data used for the mentioned Highmaps demo is for counties only. It does not include cities at all.

The solution would be to acquire GeoJSON which was on a city level instead of a county level.

Comment: All maps are available [here](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) so all additional maps, you can develop using any map in SVG / geojson

Answer (score 0):

If you are after the California's cities in GeoJSON, **[this is where you can find it](http://catalog.opendata.city/vi_VN/dataset/california-cities-polygon/resource/919bbd6c-f880-459d-abcc-4d781dbde59b?view_id=0396dd5d-c0ac-4b04-b18e-a7563ab4f135)**.

The only thing that I need to mention is that your file and my file are two different coordinate systems. Yours is [EPSG: 102243](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102243/), mine is [EPSG: 4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/).

If you have any trouble with these coordinate systems, you can always convert them from one to the other using [GeoConverter](http://geoconverter.hsr.ch/). Just make sure to expand the Advanced Options menu so you can set the input EPSG and the output EPSG.